# Add custom log handler to pyramid

Tags: python, logging, pyramid

What is a correct way to add custom log handler to pyramid? In the ini file I'm trying to define one:

```
[handler_redis]
class = RedisLogHandler
args =
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic
```

But I'm getting (not much surprising) error **"ImportError: No module named RedisLogHandler"**
I tried importing it in main **init**.py file, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a package path:

```
[handler_redis]
class = mypackage.myhandlers.RedisLogHandler
args =
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic
```

Comment: thanks. that was how I tried to do it, but it gave me errors. Turns out it was handler problem.